# R - testthat using data file outside the testing directory

Tags: r, testing, testthat

I am using `testthat` to test a package with a file tree similar to the following:

```
   .
    ├── data
    │   └── testhaplom.out
    ├── inst
    │   └── test
    │       ├── test1.r
    │       ├── tmp_S7byVksGRI6Q
    │       │   └── testm.desc
    │       └── tmp_vBcIkMN1arbn
    │           ├──testm.bin
    │           └── testm.desc
    ├── R
    │   ├── haplom.r
    │   └── winIdx.r
    └── tmp_eUG3Qb0PKuiN
        └── testhaplom.hap2.desc
```

In the `test1.r` file, I need to use the `data/testhaplom.out` file as input data for a certain function, but if I do `test_file(test1.r)`, it changes into the `inst/test` directory and cannot see the data file, giving the error below:

```
...Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'data/testhaplom.out': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are two solutions for your problem:

You could use the relative path (`../data/testhaplom.out`):

```
expect_true(file.exists(file.path("..", "data", "testhaplom.out")))
```

Or you could use `system.file` to get the location of the data directory:

```
expect_true(file.exists(file.path(system.file("data", package="YOUR_R_PACKAGE"), "testhaplom.out")))
```

I prefer the second solution.

BTW: `file.path` use the correct path separator on each platform.

Comment: Arguably, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43081458/1655567) `system.file` is a better approach.