# Where to put external files for testthat tests

Tags: r, testing, testthat

Suppose I have test like this:

```
require(testthat)
context("toy test")
test_that("toy", {
            df = my.read.file("test.txt", header=TRUE)
            expect_true(myfunc(df) == 3.14)
})
```

and this test relies on a external file test.txt, where should I put this file then?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You put these in the `testthat` folder (inside `tests`). There, you include any "external" file that you might use for your tests (or that provides some additional explanation that the user might find informative, such as in a ".txt") file. You also have your `.r` testfiles here.

Alternatively (or, in addition): you can also load your file from another location, by including the path to the file (e.g., to your `data` folder--use a relative path). However, this can result in a fragile infrastructure, since you might not be able to rely on that external location to be available at all times, in which case `testthat` will raise an error when it can not find the file.

An example of linking to a file outside of `tests`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19033987/r-testthat-using-data-file-outside-the-testing-directory?rq=1). Beware when you do this, though.

Comment: It might be useful to note that tests are run using the ```tests/testthat/``` directory as the ```getwd()```.  I often add an "input-data" folder inside ```tests/testthat``` in order to keep that directory easy to navigate.

Answer (score -2):

The right place seems to be (somewhat intuitively) `/path/to/project/tests/testthat`.