# Where do I specify random seed for tests in R package?

Tags: r, devtools, r-package, testthat

I am using `testthat` to write tests for my R package. One of my tests makes use of `jitter`. I want to make sure the test is reproducible.

Do I put `set.seed(1014)`

1. Before or after `library(testthat)` in `./tests/testthat.R`; or
2. At the top of each test file (before or after `context("Test`) in `./tests/testthat/test-function.R`; or
3. At the top of each unit test (inside of `test_that("Example works"){jitter(1)}))` in `./tests/testthat/test-function.R`?

And why?

Comment: Well, if you don't want your tests to depend on the order in which they are run, you should set the seed as close to where you are going to be selecting random numbers. So I suggest putting it inside the unit test itself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you only declare `set.seed()` once, then you always need to run the tests that use randomness in the same order in order to get the same results. However, it's probably not a good idea for unit test to only work when run in a certain order. You should set the seed as close to the time that you need to verify a random value is returned.

Here's a function that can set the seed for just a code block

```
with_seed <- function(seed, code) {
  code <- substitute(code)
  orig.seed <- .Random.seed
  on.exit(.Random.seed <<- orig.seed)
  set.seed(seed)
  eval.parent(code)
}
```

You can run it like

```
with_seed(5, rnorm(5))
```

or

```
with_seed(5, {
  a <- rnorm(5)
  b <- runif(5)
  a + b
})
```

But you will still get random numbers for the original seed outside the block.

If you would prefer to pull such a function from an existing package, the [withr::set_seed](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/withr/versions/2.1.2/topics/with_seed) appears to do the same thing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Any advice on where to put `with_seed`? :)

Comment: You could probably add that as a helper function: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35941729/r-testthat-unit-test-data-and-helper-function-conventions