# How to share a common R context amongst a subset of tests?

Tags: r, testing, automated-tests

I am working on an **R** package, using **testthat** package to automate tests *(à la Hadley)*.

Part of the tests need to access a set of files, stored into the package under folder **inst/testdata** *(see [Where should I put data for automated tests with testthat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32328802/where-to-put-data-for-automated-tests-with-testthat))*.

What is the good practice to do so, as I wish to factor the code and to reuse it from test to test ?

According to https://www.tidyverse.org/articles/2017/12/testthat-2-0-0/, I should create a **setup-xyz.R** function in the **test/testthat** folder, where *xyz* stands for a function name.

If my subset of tests is large *(hundreds of tests)* this ends up not to be really practiceable. Any proven smart solution suggestion ?

```
setup( {
lf <- list.files('../../inst/testdata', all.files = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)
}
)
```