# testhat - how to store expected result?

Tags: r, testthat

Assuming I want to write unit tests for the following function using the package `testthat`:

```
make_matrix = function(vec) {
    matrix(vec, nrow=2)
}
```

The expected function is as follows:

```
make_matrix(seq(1:4))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4
```

Following suggestions on SO I will store the input for the test functions in `inst/testdata`
[Where should I put data for automated tests with testthat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32328802/where-should-i-put-data-for-automated-tests-with-testthat)

```
#input = system.file("testdata/input.rds, package "my_package")
input = seq(1:4)

# expected_output_for_seq_1_4 = readRDS()/system.file()?
expected_output_for_seq_1_4 = matrix(c(1,2,3,4), nrow=2)

test_that("basic_test", {
    expect_equal(make_matrix(input), expected_output_for_seq_1_4)
})
```

But where and how shall I store the expected outputs? Also in `inst/testdata`? Given a more complex function there could be many expected outputs for a single input dependent on the functions' parameters

Answer (score 0):

I came up with two options:

### Option 1: `Rdata` files at `inst/testdata`

As per the most accepted answer in the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32328802/where-should-i-put-data-for-automated-tests-with-testthat), I would go to save it in `inst/testdata`, but using RData files that allows saving multiple objects in one file. This way you can save all the expected outputs for related tests in the same file:

```
inst/testdata/expected_outputs_function1.Rdata # contains all the outputs for function1
inst/testdata/expected_outputs_function2.Rdata # contains all the outputs for function2
```

### Option 2: R files to generate the outputs on the fly

However, if the project/package is complex, or it needs big expected outputs, the previous method can generate RData files that exceed the [package size policy at CRAN](https://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/r/size-and-limitations-of-packages-on-cran/) (only relevant if you want to upload the package to CRAN). So, other option is store the code generating the expected outputs in `inst/testdata/expected_outputs.R` and add
`source(system.file("testdata/expected_outputs.R", package "my_package"))` before executing the tests:

**expected_outputs.R**

```
expected_output_for_seq_1_4 <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4), nrow=2)
expected_output_for_data_frame <- {code to generate output for data_frame here}
{...}
```

Drawback for this method is that if the expected outputs take long time to calculate, tests are not gonna be fast.