# Where to put test data in R package for R CMD CHECK

Tags: r, unit-testing, devtools, r-package, testthat

This question is a near duplicate of [Q32328802 - testdata for testthat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32328802/where-should-i-put-data-for-automated-tests-with-testthat). The difference is that I'm looking for a more specific answer as it relates to `devtools::check`. **Specifically, how do I get `devtools::check()` to recognize and load my test data?**

My package structure for `tests/testthat.R` and `tests/testthat/setup-testdata.R` is described below (and github is linked at the bottom of the post). I have tried the following:

- Following the above linked question, I have placed the test data in `inst/testdata`. As this is not working, I have also tried other locations (eg. `tests/`, `tests/testthat`). None of these locations work.
- I have also tried renaming `helper-testdata.R` as `setup-testdata.R` and get the same failing results.
- `devtools::check()` does not appear to accurately recognize the `load(system.file(...))` command. It similarly does not recognize if I spell the file name out (ie. do not use `system.file()`). Omitting the load command also doesn't work.

### `tests/`:

**`testthat.R`**

```
library(synthACS)
library(testthat)

test_check("synthACS")
```

**`testthat/setup-testdata.R`** has a single line in it:

```
load(system.file("testdata", 'dat-acsdata.Rda', package= "synthACS"))
# run interactively, this line of code loads the data accurately.
# within devtools::check() it appears to return an empty string ("") for
# file location
```

### Checking my package

```
R> devtools::test(synthACS)
══ Results ═════════════════════════

OK:       388
Failed:   0
Warnings: 0
Skipped:  0

R> devtools::check(synthACS)
...
─  checking tests ...
E  Running ‘testthat.R’ (1.5s)

── Test failures ─────────────────────

> library(testthat)
> 
> load(system.file("testdata", 'acsdata.rda', package= "synthACS"))
> test_check("synthACS")
 ----------- FAILURE REPORT -------------- 
... indicates that the data is not loaded ...
```

Any help appreciated!

#### Edit links to full code:

- package: https://github.com/alexWhitworth/synthACS
- failing travis-ci build: https://travis-ci.org/github/alexWhitworth/synthACS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is to use `readRDS`, which means saving each object separately via `saveRDS`

eg.

`my_data <- readRDS(file= system.file("testdata", 'dat-mydata.rds', package= "synthACS"))`

Comment: so, just to follow up... the actual location of the files wasn't the issue with CHECK, it was something about using RDA vs RDS? Any clarity on what the problem was?

Comment: For me, this solution is not working. I have the following `my_data <- readRDS(file= system.file("tests", "testthat", "testdata", "my_data.rds", package = "my_package"))`.
The error message:
`Error: cannot open the connection
Backtrace:
    x
 1. \-base::readRDS(...) test_user_input.R:3:2
 2.   \-base::gzfile(file, "rb")`.
What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

R CMD check doesn't care what is in your /tests directory, as long as there's a file it can run to execute your tests (and they pass). Similarly, testthat doesn't care about other directories under /tests. So you can put your file in a directory there, say in /tests/resources.

Example here: https://github.com/jeroen/openssl/tree/master/tests

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have tried moving the file `sysdata.rda` to multiple different directories. This does not resolve how to `load()` the file as part of test_check()

Comment: Create a `setup.R` file under tests/testthat to do any pre-testing setup, see the help for testthat

Comment: While I appreciate the help, this does not resolve for me. Per the testthat documentation i have tried both `helper-` and `setup-` files (see my OP). The file is not working properly

Comment: Put the file in tests/resources/whatver.rda, and have a tests/testthat/setup.R file containing the line `load("../resources/whatever.rda")`

Comment: This is essentially what I'm already doing, except using `load("../resources/whatever.rda")` instead of `load(system.file(...))`. Regardless of approach, it does not work. I get the same error with your suggested approach

Comment: DON'T USE `system.file`. Use the relative path I gave there.

Comment: Try it again 123

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214842/discussion-between-alex-w-and-hong-ooi).